# Issues saving select options into a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to save options of a multiple select into a variable with jQuery like this:

```
let lista_alumnos = $("#nomatriculas_asignatura").children('option');
```

But when the user changes the selected options, the variable `lista_alumnos` changes its content too. How can I prevent that?

I need `lista_alumnos` to not change its value until web page refresh.

Comment: it changes its content in which way? can tou provide a working snippet or example of before/after?

Comment: Did you try: `.children('option:selected').text()` ?  You variable points at the elements themselves, instead, make it point to the values, which won't change unless you update the variable.

Comment: Do you want to get the children that are selected or the values of the selected options?

Comment: unclear what you're asking

Comment: I have two multiple `<select>` and the user can transfer options between them. My intention is to save the original options first and restore them later in the `<select>` elements but `lista_alumnos` variable only saves the `<select>` reference so, when user change the `<select>` content, `lista_alumnos` content changes too.

Answer (score 0):

use array to store selected values.

your lista_alumnos is changing with change of select because you are storing reference of select options. try storing values rather then reference.

```js
function getvalue(){
  var val = new Array();
  $("select option:selected").each(function(){
    val.push($(this).val());
  });
  
  console.log(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="get value" onclick="getvalue()"/>
```

Comment: Easier to use `.map()` than `new Array()  ..  push`

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to save the information in jQuery is approaching by using id.
If you have nested select option give id.

```
children('option:selected').val();     
var lista_alumnos = $("#nomatriculas_asignatura").val();
```

> Saving in a variable is not good sometimes so use arrays